# updating attributes with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models User and Advert. User has_many :adverts and Advert belongs_to :user. I use accepts_nested_attributes_for to update adverts attributes. This is how I do it:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
   @user = current_user 
   @user.update_attributes(adverts_attributes: [{id: ???, show_advert: false}])
end
```

For @user to be able to update advert he needs to have advert ID. If I just type ID advert e.g. 112 this works fine. I have also tried this way:

```
Advert.all.each do |advert|
  @advert = advert.id
end
```

Worked only for oldest advert.

So how can I access advert ID?

```
<Advert id: 356, created_at: "2015-04-06 00:54:29", updated_at: "2015-04-06 00:54:29", user_id: 66, show_advert: true> 

<User id: 66, email: "xxx@xxx", encrypted_password: "xxx", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 69, current_sign_in_at: "2015-04-04 22:25:47", last_sign_in_at: "2015-04-04 18:11:27", current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:xxx>, last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:xxx>, created_at: "2015-03-07 21:32:13", updated_at: "2015-04-05 01:40:29">
```

Form for cancel plan

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => users_cancel_plan_path, :html => { id: 'cancel_plan', :method => :put }) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit "Cancel Subscription", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: inspect and add your params in the quesiton.

Comment: @architgupta I have added params

Answer (score 4):

Inside the model, you need to have -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adverts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adverts
end
```

and you should also need to keep the whitelisting as :

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, .., adverts_attributes: [:id, :addr1, ..])
  end
end
```

Little note from the [:update_only](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) documentation :

> For a one-to-one association, this option allows you to specify how nested attributes are to be used when an associated record already exists. In general, an existing record may either be updated with the new set of attribute values or be replaced by a wholly new record containing those values. **By default the :update_only option is false and the nested attributes are used to update the existing record only if they include the record's `:id` value. Otherwise a new record will be instantiated and used to replace the existing one**. However if the :update_only option is true, the nested attributes are used to update the record's attributes always, regardless of whether the :id is present. **The option is ignored for collection associations.**

Read [*Nested Forms*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) guide to understand how to work with *nested* forms.

Comment: In my case I have one-to-many, as far as I understand and I need to have :id value to update existing record when using nested attributes.

Comment: Do you have idea how could I get advert :id?

Comment: It depends on how your form you created.. Did you read the rails guide link ?

Comment: Do you mean f.fields_for :adverts do |builder| ? No, I don't have this in my form. Do I have any other option?

Comment: so from where you are getting the other attributes, that's you were trying to update?

Comment: My scenario look like that: User wants to cancel his paid plan. When action cancel_plan is triggered all the adverts should become hidden from the search. For that I have show_advert (in Advert) attribute with true or false. Look pretty simple, but  I'm missing something basic, because don't really understand how to get this advert :id

Comment: I use Rails 4, so no worries about attributes

Comment: @vitdes I have idea. Can you show the form, where the `cancel_plan` is present. Just put it in your post. If there you have the access the object, then you can pass the `id` as a **query parameter**..

Comment: No, I did not solved it yet. I though I would pass <% hidden_field_tag 'advert', "here id" %>, but then I realized that I cannot derive advert :id.

Comment: What is the resource object ? You need to pass through this helper users_cancel_plan_path(id: Value) like that

Comment: The resource object is user. By passing users_cancel_plan_path(id: Value) I would supply user :id ? If so this doesn't help me